# Function that behaves as dup2

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, io, posix

I am reading the book Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment and I have tried to solve the following exercise: Write a function that performs the same actions as `dup2`, but without using `fcntl`

My question: What can I improve? What problems may arise?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "lab.h"
/**
 * @brief      
 * { Check if the file descriptor fd is legal. If it is not legal, set errno and }
 * { errnum to EBADF. }
 *
 * @param[in]  fd      { parameter_description }
 * @param      errnum  The errnum
 *
 * @return     { description_of_the_return_value }
 */
static inline bool fd_is_valid(int fd, int *errnum)
{   // Back up the original errno to prevent errno from being
    // EBADF before
    int olderr = errno;
    if (errno == EBADF)
        errno = 0;
    int newfd = dup(fd);
    if (newfd != -1 || errno != EBADF)
    { // legal, restore errno to its original value
        close(newfd);
        errno = olderr;
        return true;
    }
    else
    { // is not legal, errno and errnum are set to EBADF
        errno = *errnum = EBADF;
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief      The wrapper function of dup() does not change errno. 
 *             If the dup call fails,
 *             set errnum to be the error code.
 *
 * @param[in]  oldfd   The oldfd
 * @param      errnum  The errnum
 *
 * @return     { description_of_the_return_value }
 */
static inline int dup_checked(int oldfd, int *errnum)
{
    int olderr = errno;
    int newfd = dup(oldfd);
    if (newfd == -1)
        *errnum = errno;
    errno = olderr;
    return newfd;
}

/**
 * @brief      my implementation of dup2
 *
 * @param[in]  oldfd   The oldfd
 * @param[in]  newfd   The newfd
 * @param      errnum  The errnum
 *
 * @return     { description_of_the_return_value }
 */
static inline int mydup2_imp(int oldfd, int newfd, int *errnum)
{
    close(newfd);
    int *fds = (int *)calloc(newfd + 1, sizeof(int));
    int index = 0;
    int res = -1;
    /*we will then use up all lower file descriptors untill we
     reach newfile, remember dup will automatically return the
     lowest available closed file descriptor*/
    for (; index < (newfd + 1); ++index)
    {
        fds[index] = dup_checked(oldfd, errnum);
        if (fds[index] == -1 || fds[index] == newfd)
        {
            res = fds[index];
            break;
        }
    } // fds[index] is -1 or newfd
    for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
    {
        close(fds[i]);
    }
    free(fds);
    return res;
}

int mydup2(int oldfd, int newfd)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    int res = -1;
    // 1. Check if the file descriptor range is legal
    int tbl_size = getdtablesize();
    if (oldfd < 0 || oldfd >= tbl_size || newfd < 0 || newfd >= tbl_size)
    {
        errnum = EBADF;
        goto exit_mydup2;
    }
    // 2. Check if oldfd is open, if not open, errnum is set to EBADF
    if (!fd_is_valid(oldfd, &errnum))
        goto exit_mydup2;
    // 3. Check if oldfd is the same as newfd
    if (oldfd == newfd)
    {
        res = oldfd;
        goto exit_mydup2;
    }
    // 4. Execute the actual dup2 process
    res = mydup2_imp(oldfd, newfd, &errnum);

exit_mydup2:
    errno = errnum;
    return res;
}

/**
 * @brief      main function to test my function
 *
 * @return     error code to the OS
 */
int main()
{
    int fd = 20;
    mydup2(STDOUT_FILENO, fd);
    err_ret("");
    return 0;
}
```

lab.h:

```
/* Our own header, to be included *after* all standard system headers */

#ifndef __LAB_H__
#define __LAB_H__

#include    <sys/types.h>   /* required for some of our prototypes */
#include    <stdio.h>       /* for convenience */
#include    <stdlib.h>      /* for convenience */
#include    <string.h>      /* for convenience */
#include    <unistd.h>      /* for convenience */

#define MAXLINE 4096            /* max line length */

#define FILE_MODE   (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)
                    /* default file access permissions for new files */
#define DIR_MODE    (FILE_MODE | S_IXUSR | S_IXGRP | S_IXOTH)
                    /* default permissions for new directories */


                    /* prototypes for our own functions */
char    *path_alloc(int *);         /* {Prog pathalloc} */
int      open_max(void);            /* {Prog openmax} */
void     clr_fl(int, int);          /* {Prog setfl} */
void     set_fl(int, int);          /* {Prog setfl} */

void    err_dump(const char *, ...);    /* {App misc_source} */
void    err_msg(const char *, ...);
void    err_quit(const char *, ...);
void    err_ret(const char *, ...);
void    err_sys(const char *, ...);

#endif  /* __LAB_H__ */
```

Comment: Why are you casting the return value from `calloc()`?

Answer (score 3):

After this line:

> ```
> int *fds = (int *)calloc(newfd + 1, sizeof(int));
> ```

`fds` may be a null pointer, so when we reach here:

> ```
>     fds[index] = dup_checked(oldfd, errnum);
> ```

we have Undefined Behaviour.

We need to fix that:

```
int *fds = calloc(newfd + 1, sizeof *fds);
if (!fds) {
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return -1;
}
```

Notice also that there's no need write a cast to assign a `void*` value to `int*` variable, and most readers prefer a `sizeof` expression that is independent of the target's type.

Comment: If you look at other answers this user has received you will find testing of memory allocation mentioned previously, also the cast.

Comment: It's sad when askers don't apply what they learn.  Second time today I've seen that happen.  :-(

Answer (score -1):

Think big.  Consider how your code should be separated into various files for future use like `lab2.c, mydup2.h, mydup2.c, err.h`, ...

**Good parameter checks**

Nice

```
if (oldfd < 0 || oldfd >= tbl_size || newfd < 0 || newfd >= tbl_size)
```

**Weak approach**

Header has `/* Our own header, to be included *after* all standard system headers */`.

`lab.h` includes some unnecessary ones.  Do not include them for convenience.  Let the .c file include what it wants and not additional ones you *think* are useful.

```
#include    <stdio.h>       /* for convenience */
#include    <stdlib.h>      /* for convenience */
#include    <string.h>      /* for convenience */
#include    <unistd.h>      /* for convenience */
```

**Test include independence**

For `lab.c`, include `lab.h` *first* to verify that it works without additional include files.

When other .c files include `lab.h`, compilation should work regardless of the order of include files that .c file uses.

**Manage namespace**

`lab.h` surprisingly creates names like `MAXLINE`, `FILE_MODE`, `DIR_MODE`, `path_alloc`, `open_max`, `clr_fl`, `err_...`, ...

This will conflict with other object files.  Consider uniform prefix like `LAB2_...`, `lab2_....` or separate out this wide spread of names into `err.h`, `my_file.h`, ...

**Omission of useful names**

Function prototype argument lack parameter names.  This loses a valuable opportunity to convey to users of these function the role of the parameters.  Do **not** rely on the .c to explain the overall functionality of a public function.  That info belongs in the .h file.  Consider how you use function like `fopen(), sqrt(), memcpy(), strcpy()`.  You generally do not examine their implementations to understand how to use them.

```
// void    err_msg(const char *, ...);
// void    err_quit(const char *, ...);

void    err_msg(const char *format, ...);
void    err_quit(const char *format, ...);
```

**Mixed case**

Some comments are in sentence case.

some comments are in lower case

Better to use one style.  Sentence case conveys the most information.

**Uninformative comment**

```
//              v- Incomplete documentation. -v
* @return     { description_of_the_return_value }
```

**Mis-comment**

`errnum` is not the error number.  `errnum` is a *pointer* to the saved error number.

```
 * @param[in]  oldfd   The oldfd
 * @param      errnum  The errnum
 *
 * @return     { description_of_the_return_value }
 */
static inline int dup_checked(int oldfd, int *errnum)
```